# import arcpy in the VS Code terminal fails

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, arcpy

I am trying to get arcpy to import in the vs code terminal (running python 2.7 as an arcgis install). It runs fine if I open a command window, initiate python, and import arcpy. It also works within the ArcGIS environment. This leads me to beloeve that the error below is inaccurate. Importing arcpy does not work at the VS Code terminal. How can I resolve this?

```
>>> import arcpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.6\ArcPy\arcpy\__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
    import numpy
File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.6\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
    from . import add_newdocs
File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.6\lib\site-packages\numpy\add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.6\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .type_check import *
File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.6\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\type_check.py", line 11, in <module>
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.6\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError:
Importing the multiarray numpy extension module failed.  Most
likely you are trying to import a failed build of numpy.
If you're working with a numpy git repo, try `git clean -xdf` (removes all
files not under version control).  Otherwise reinstall numpy.

Original error was: DLL load failed: The specified path is invalid.
```

Comment: Do you have VSCode and ArcPy set up to use the same Python installation?

Comment: Yes!:

VS Code terminal:
    `>>> import sys
    >>> sys.executable
    'C:\\Python27\\ArcGIS10.6\\python.exe'`

CMD:
    `>>> import sys
    >>> sys.executable
    'C:\\Python27\\ArcGIS10.6\\python.exe'`

Arc (ha, ha):
    `>>> import sys
    >>> sys.executable
    'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\ArcGIS\\Desktop10.6\\bin\\ArcMap.exe'`

i could not get this to format as I wanted, but I hope you see the answer verified.